# PDO Retrieve column name that data was found from

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, pdo

My apologies for the potentially difficult-to-understand title, it proved hard to condense my question.

I'm currently using PDO to search through multiple columns for a match, and returning the rows that have a match.

Simplified:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE firstname = ? OR lastname = ?"
```

I loop through the results etc etc.

However, my employer wants to be told which column the match occurred in (for example 'firstname' should be returned if the match happened in the 'firstname' column).

As far as I have searched, there isn't any kind of PDO function or function to do this, not to mention it's difficult to search due to tricky wording.

I was thinking of using the returned data to then again search for the matching column, but I'm still unsure what to use, `fetchColumn` seems the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    *,
    firstname = :firstname AS found_in_firstname,
    lastname = :lastname AS found_in_lastname
FROM
    patient
WHERE
    firstname = :firstname OR lastname = :lastname
```

This query will return the same result as yours, but will contain two extra columns `found_in_firstname` and `found_in_lastname` with boolean value indicating whether given coulmn mached search criteria.

Comment: Be wary of re-using the named parameters. Unless emulating prepared statements, this will trigger an error.